# Do we have functionality in Text Edit control to list cookie values?

Tags: devexpress, xtraeditors

I have a Devexpress textEdit control in windows application. Do we have option to list the cokkie values while typing the text in the texteditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextEdit does not support the auto complete functionality you are asking about.  A possible solution is to use the ComboBoxEdit or LookupEdit controls.  Both of them can hold a list of items shown in the dropdown window.  Finally, you should write a code which will the editors with values stored in cookies.